# Disable all user interaction for MKMapView except for a given MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a MKMapView and a few MKAnnotationViews on my map.

When a certain event happens, I would like to disable user interaction on my MKMapView but leave interaction on my MKAnnotationView available.

Ideally, it would be

```
self.mapView.userInteraction = NO;
self.myAnnotationView.userInteraction = YES;
```

Printing

```
[self.mapView recursiveDescription]
```

I have found that my annotation view is nested in MKNewAnnotationContainerView which doesn't have a publicly exposed property on Apple's class reference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting scrollEnabled, zoomEnabled, pitchEnabled, and rotateEnabled to NO (but leaving userInteractionEnabled as YES)?

Comment: Thanks Anna! Just tried it and works like a gem! Could you post it as the answer so I can mark it answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the mapView, set `scrollEnabled`, `zoomEnabled`, `pitchEnabled`, and `rotateEnabled` to `NO` and leave `userInteractionEnabled` as `YES`.

This way, the annotation views will still be enabled.

For `pitchEnabled` and `rotateEnabled`, you may want to check if those properties exist before setting them (eg. check if the map view `respondsToSelector:@selector(setPitchEnabled)`, etc.) since they were added in iOS 7.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder property existence reminder!